# Establish connection between socket listener servers

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have many servers running on different machines and listening to their well known IP addresses and ports.
I want to establish a connection between the servers (first try wins) and authenticate the caller based on the well known IPAddress/port pair.

The problem what I have is, that I can't reuse the listener port for starting a new connection - so this authentication is not possible (even if a connection socket would be uniquely identifiable later by the communication instance parameters).

I would like to keep the symmetry between the partners (there is nothing like a 'master' coordinating the nodes).
Is there a solution for this problem?

[As I know, SO_REUSEADDR was not meant for this ...]

UPDATED:
I just defined some configuration containing IPAddress and port number pairs. The idea is to establish the connections using exactly these pairs. So the parties having the configuration can easily check the incoming connections.
Later I would like to place everything behind xinetd and let him verifying the incoming address/port combinations.

SUMMARY:
Event if is theoretically possible to establish a network by using machine specific (IPAddress, port) pairs, there is no possibility to realize it with equivalent communication nodes ('half' of them has to be clients, the other half servers).
Am i right?
[ we can discuss also the motivation behind the problem, but this is *not* the question ]

Comment: Instead of using the same port as the servers are listening on, why not bind the outgoing connection to another specified port? A common example would be `listening_port_number + 1`.

Comment: ... and continue so for all the network nodes? It can be hardly authorized then ...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by **well known IP addresses and ports**? If its standard service, like SMTP, how you can add authenticate service based on ip-port pairs, on top of SMTP?

Comment: I just defined some configuration containing ip-address and port number pairs. The idea is to establish the connections using _exactly_ these pairs. So the parties having the configuration can easily check the incoming connections.

Comment: I don't think you really gain any security by trying to "authenticate" based on the outgoing port number -- a hypothetical malicious application running on the same server could equally well usurp that well-known port to make its phony connection, so you're basically left with IP-address based security.

Comment: of course, there is an additional credential check.

Answer (score 0):

I must say relying on IP address is not true security. But, if that's what you have chosen to do, you can do one of the following

- Use UDP instead of TCP. You can easily send/receive messages from the same port.
- Use a pair of ports for TCP. One for sending, other for receiving.